# fetch selected values using jQuery

Tags: jquery

i am using this [Dual Listbox Plugin](http://www.meadmiracle.com/dlb/DLBDocumentation.aspx), i am trying to fetch the values using onClick event of jQuery that has been selected from box1 to box2,

this is the code i am using

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form" id="purchaseEditUpdateItemForm">
<div class="widget">
    <div class="title">
        <img src="/images/icons/dark/full2.png" alt="" class="titleIcon" />
        <a href="#" class="button blueB" id="purchaseEditUpdateItemBtn" style="margin: 4px;">
            <span>Update</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="leftPart">
            <div class="filter">
                <span>Filter:</span>
                <input type="text" id="box1Filter" class="boxFilter" />
                <input type="button" id="box1Clear" class="fBtn" value="x" />
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <select id="box1View" multiple="multiple" class="multiple" style="height:200px;">
                <option value="5">ITEM005</option>
                <option value="6">ITEM006</option>
                <option value="7">ITEM007</option>
                <option value="8">ITEM008</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <span id="box1Counter" class="countLabel"></span>
            <div class="dn">
                <select id="box1Storage" name="box1Storage"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dualControl">
            <button id="to2" type="button" class="basic mr5 mb15">&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</button>
            <button id="allTo2" type="button" class="basic">&nbsp;&gt;&gt;&nbsp;</button>
            <br />
            <button id="to1" type="button" class="basic mr5">&nbsp;&lt;&nbsp;</button>
            <button id="allTo1" type="button" class="basic">&nbsp;&lt;&lt;&nbsp;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="rightPart">
            <div class="filter">
                <span>Filter:</span>
                <input type="text" id="box2Filter" class="boxFilter" />
                <input type="button" id="box2Clear" class="fBtn" value="x" />
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <select id="box2View" multiple="multiple" class="multiple" style="height:200px;">
                <option value="1">ITEM001</option>
                <option value="2">ITEM002</option>
                <option value="3">ITEM003</option>
                <option value="4">ITEM004</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <span id="box2Counter" class="countLabel"></span>
            <div class="dn">
                <select id="box2Storage"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

i am trying something like? (i know the below code is not practical)

```
$('#purchaseEditUpdateItemBtn').live('click', function(){
    var formData = $('#purchaseEditUpdateItemForm').serialize();
});
```

Comment: You want all items in #box2view or the items which are copied from box1 to box2 or may be something else?

Comment: you got it correct, actually i just want the items from `#box2View`

Comment: You have already found the solution thats great, btw if it is just to see the items then: `$('#box2View').select().text() `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
$('#purchaseEditUpdateItemBtn').click(function(){
   //If the items do not get the "selected" attribute, you could also use this:
   var items = $("select#boxview2 option");

$.each(items, function(index, elem){
   //this will log the value for each item inside the boxview2 list
   console.log(elem.val);
});
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: you are close, i solved it myself. i used this code to fetch values from box2View 
`$('#purchaseEditUpdateItemBtn').live('click', function(){
        var select = []; 
        $('#box2View option').each(function(i, selected){ 
            select[i] = $(selected).val(); 
        });
        console.log(select);
        return false;
    });`

Answer (score 1):

when using `serialize()` form elements must have `name` attributes:

```
<select name='box1View' id="box1View" multiple="multiple" class="multiple" style="height:200px;">
    <option value="5" selcted>ITEM005</option>
    <option value="6">ITEM006</option>
    <option value="7">ITEM007</option>
    <option value="8">ITEM008</option>
</select>
```

please note that `live` is deprecated, you can use `on()` method instead, try the following:

```
$('form').on('click', 'a.button', function(){
    var formData = $('select').serialize();
});
```

Comment: this does not work, prints empty string in console, i have added the name attribute to the select element though :(

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar have you added `name` attributes?

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar you should first select a value, try this http://jsfiddle.net/TfHpj/

Comment: okay, so jQuery serialize() requires the values to be selected first in multiple select element? that makes sense. but given the plugin implementation i won't be selecting the values from select box. i was hoping jQuery would do the magic for me :D, anyhow i think i should stick with @Rob Angelier's solution. and thank you.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar there is no need for using jQuery, you can use `selected` attribute.

Comment: it is good to know different versions of the solution, but you see, the plugin is designed such that, the selected attribute won't be used at all, for example the end user will select the items from box1View and put it in box2View, all i need is all the values from box2View if i give the select attribute here for all the items in the box2View, it doesn't makes much sense. isn't it?

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar i'm not sure what you mean, Okay.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#purchaseEditUpdateItemBtn").click(function(event){
console.log("Selected from box 1 "+$("select#box1View option:selected")); // selected from #box1View
console.log("Selected from box 2 "+$("select#box2View option:selected")); // selected from #vow2View
console.log($("#purchaseEditUpdateItemForm").serialize());
});
```

Comment: If you look in the HTML source, you can see that none of the items get the "selected" attribute.

Comment: In that case, You should look at my answer